# How to obtain a line-level measure of the similarity of two aligned texts with Spacy?

Tags: python, list, file-handling, spacy

I have two aligned documents, in English, each with the same number of lines (about 30k). I want to obtain a measure of the similarity per line, that is, *line_1* in *text_a* against *line_1* in *text_b*, *line_2* in *text_a* against *line_2* in *text_b* and so on. (Each line may contain more than one sentence) I've done this:

```
import spacy 
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

file_a = open('text-1.txt', 'r')
file_b = open ('text-2.txt', 'r')
a_doc = nlp(file_a)
b_doc = nlp(file_b)

for a,b in zip(a_doc, b_doc):    
    print("similarity:", a.similarity(b))
```

But I get the following error:

```
if len(text) > self.max_length:
TypeError: object of type '_io.TextIOWrapper' has no len()
```

Can you help me? It's very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nlp()` expects a string, not a file object. I edited your code slightly to this:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

file_a = open('text-1.txt', 'r').read()
file_b = open ('text-2.txt', 'r').read()
a_doc = nlp(file_a)
b_doc = nlp(file_b)

for a,b in zip(a_doc, b_doc):
    print("similarity:", a.similarity(b))
```

and it ran fine

Answer (score 0):

nlp expects a string, not a file handler object.

Try this

```
a_doc = nlp("".join(file_a.readlines()))
b_doc = nlp("".join(file_b.readlines()))
```